# Splitting a list by indexes

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to build an efficient function for splitting a list of any size by any given number of indices. This method works and it took me a few hours to get it right (I hate how easy it is to get things wrong when using indexes).

Am I over-thinking this? Can you help me minimize the code? I am just not seeing it. ALSO, is there any way to simplify the input of so many variables such as in this situation?

```
def lindexsplit(List,*lindex):

    index = list(lindex)

    index.sort()

    templist1 = []
    templist2 = []
    templist3 = []

    breakcounter = 0
    itemcounter = 0
    finalcounter = 0


    numberofbreaks = len(index)
    totalitems = len(List)

    lastindexval = index[(len(index)-1)]
    finalcounttrigger = (totalitems-(lastindexval+1))

    for item in List:

        itemcounter += 1

        indexofitem = itemcounter - 1

        nextbreakindex = index[breakcounter]

        #Less than the last cut
        if breakcounter <= numberofbreaks:

            if indexofitem < nextbreakindex:

                templist1.append(item)

            elif breakcounter < (numberofbreaks - 1):

                templist1.append(item)

                templist2.append(templist1)

                templist1 = []

                breakcounter +=1

            else:

                if indexofitem <= lastindexval and indexofitem <= totalitems:

                    templist1.append(item)

                    templist2.append(templist1)

                    templist1 = []

                else:

                    if indexofitem >= lastindexval and indexofitem < totalitems + 1:

                        finalcounter += 1

                        templist3.append(item)

                        if finalcounter == finalcounttrigger:

                            templist2.append(templist3)


    return templist2
```

Example:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,10,11,12,13,14,15]
lindexsplit(mylist,3,5,8)
return [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview.stackexchange. In order to make reviewing easier for everyone, can you tell us a bit more about what your function is supposed to do and how it does it ? Also, examples are more than welcome :-)

Comment: The function takes a list of any set of objects and slices that list at any number of sorted indexes given as arguments in the second part of the function :) - I noticed that there was no split method for lists, so I made my own

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this explanation. Also, if you could add an example, that would make things much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your example, this is exactly what I was hoping for. Unfortunately, the output I get is `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]` and not the one you've provided.

Comment: That is the correct output! I had a index problem in the version I used to give the output. I will correct it. Yours is the correct working example of my code. Is there a way to make it more efficient?

Comment: Is there anyway to get the python developers to include this a similar method in the next python updates?

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but this should be a one-liner: `return [seq[i:j] for i, j in zip((0,) + indices, indices + (None,))]`, as shown in the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198512/split-a-list-into-parts-based-on-a-set-of-indexes-in-python).  I'm also not sure why your indices are 1-based rather than 0-based: if I pass `3` as an index to your function, I would expect a split after the third element, not after the fourth.

Answer (score 17):

There is a lot simpler way to do this. You can use [list slicing](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/2017002/python-101-unit-1-understanding-indices-and-slicing) and the [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

List slicing essentially cuts up a given list into sections. The general form is `list[start:stop:step]`. The `start` section of a slice designates the first index of the list we want to **included** in our slice. The `stop` section designates the first index of the list we want **excluded** in our slice. The `step` section defines how many indices we are moving as well as in which direction (based on whether it is positive or negative). An example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x[1:3]
[2, 3]
>>> x[2:]
[3, 4]
>>> x[0:4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x[0:4:1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x[0:4:2]
[1, 3]
>>> x[0:4:3]
[1, 4]
>>> x[0:4:4]
[1]
>>> x[0:4:5]
[1]
```

---

The zip function takes sequences and creates a zip object that contains tuples of their corresponding index elements:

```
>>> for pair in zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']):
...    print(pair)
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
```

---

You can combine these two strategies to simplify your function. Here is my version of your `lindexsplit` function:

```
def lindexsplit(some_list, *args):
    # Checks to see if any extra arguments were passed. If so,
    # prepend the 0th index and append the final index of the 
    # passed list. This saves from having to check for the beginning
    # and end of args in the for-loop. Also, increment each value in 
    # args to get the desired behavior.
    if args:
        args = (0,) + tuple(data+1 for data in args) + (len(some_list)+1,)

    # For a little more brevity, here is the list comprehension of the following
    # statements:
    #    return [some_list[start:end] for start, end in zip(args, args[1:])]
    my_list = []
    for start, end in zip(args, args[1:]):
        my_list.append(some_list[start:end])
    return my_list
```

---

Answer (score 5):

A few cosmetic changes to makes your code more beautiful/pythonic :

**Fix formatting**

- Remove some line breaks as it makes the code harder to read
- Change variables name to follow [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Your code lacks documentation making it hard to understand.

**Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)**

Enumerate does exactly what you are trying to achieve : keep track of the index while looping on an iterable. Just use `for indexofitem,item in enumerate(List):`.

**Remove levels of nested logic**

Using `elif`, you could make your code a bit easier to follow. The inside of the `for-loop` becomes :

```
    if breakcounter <= numberofbreaks:
        if indexofitem < nextbreakindex:
            templist1.append(item)
        elif breakcounter < (numberofbreaks - 1):
            templist1.append(item)
            templist2.append(templist1)
            templist1 = []
            breakcounter +=1
        elif indexofitem <= lastindexval and indexofitem <= totalitems:
            templist1.append(item)
            templist2.append(templist1)
            templist1 = []
        elif indexofitem >= lastindexval and indexofitem < totalitems + 1:
            finalcounter += 1
            templist3.append(item)
            if finalcounter == finalcounttrigger:
                templist2.append(templist3)
```

**Rewrite your comparisons**

In Python, you can write comparisons in a very natural way : `indexofitem >= lastindexval and indexofitem < totalitems + 1` becomes `lastindexval <= indexofitem < totalitems + 1`.

**Use smart indices to get the last element of array**

You can rewrite `lastindexval = index[(len(index)-1)]` with the much clearer `lastindexval = index[-1]`.

**Rethink your logic**

You have `totalitems = len(List)` and `indexofitem` going from `0` to `len(List) - 1` (included). Thus, `indexofitem <= totalitems` is not an interesting condition to check. The same goes for `indexofitem < totalitems + 1`.

Once this is removed, we have :

```
    #Less than the last cut
    if breakcounter <= numberofbreaks:
        if indexofitem < nextbreakindex:
            templist1.append(item)
        elif breakcounter < (numberofbreaks - 1):
            templist1.append(item)
            templist2.append(templist1)
            templist1 = []
            breakcounter +=1
        elif indexofitem <= lastindexval:
            templist1.append(item)
            templist2.append(templist1)
            templist1 = []
        elif lastindexval <= indexofitem:
            finalcounter += 1
            templist3.append(item)
            if finalcounter == finalcounttrigger:
                templist2.append(templist3)
```

**Re-think your logic (bis)**

On the code above, the last 2 `elif` checks are a bit redundant : if we don't go into the `indexofitem <= lastindexval` block then we must have `lastindexval < indexofitem` and ``lastindexval <= indexofitem` must be true.

After cleaning this, the code looks like :

```
    for indexofitem,item in enumerate(List):
        nextbreakindex = index[breakcounter]

        #Less than the last cut
        if breakcounter <= numberofbreaks:
            if indexofitem < nextbreakindex:
                templist1.append(item)
            elif breakcounter < (numberofbreaks - 1):
                templist1.append(item)
                templist2.append(templist1)
                templist1 = []
                breakcounter +=1
            elif indexofitem <= lastindexval:
                templist1.append(item)
                templist2.append(templist1)
                templist1 = []
            else:
                finalcounter += 1
                templist3.append(item)
                if finalcounter == finalcounttrigger:
                    templist2.append(templist3)
    return templist2
```

**Re-think your logic (ter)**

Nothing happens in the loop if `breakcounter > numberofbreaks` as `breakcounter` and `numberofbreaks` are not changed. If this is really the case, we might as well just break out of the loop. However, things are even better than this : once again we are in a situation that cannot happen. This can be seen in two different ways :

- if `breakcounter` was to be bigger than `numberofbreaks`, `nextbreakindex = index[breakcounter]` would have thrown an exception.
- `breakcounter` only gets incremented one element at a time. This happens only if `breakcounter < (numberofbreaks - 1)`. Thus, once `breakcounter` reaches `numberofbreaks - 1`, it stops growing.

At the end of this rewriting, your code looks like :

```
def lindexsplit(List,*lindex):
    index = list(lindex)
    index.sort()

    templist1 = []
    templist2 = []
    templist3 = []

    breakcounter = 0
    finalcounter = 0

    numberofbreaks = len(index)

    lastindexval = index[-1]
    finalcounttrigger = (len(List)-(lastindexval+1))

    for indexofitem,item in enumerate(List):
        nextbreakindex = index[breakcounter]

        if indexofitem < nextbreakindex:
            print "A"
            templist1.append(item)
        elif breakcounter < (numberofbreaks - 1):
            print "B"
            templist1.append(item)
            templist2.append(templist1)
            templist1 = []
            breakcounter +=1
        elif indexofitem <= lastindexval:
            print "C"
            templist1.append(item)
            templist2.append(templist1)
            templist1 = []
        else:
            print "D"
            finalcounter += 1
            templist3.append(item)
            if finalcounter == finalcounttrigger:
                templist2.append(templist3)
    return templist2
```

I reckon there is still a lot more to improve and a much more simple solution could be written (as suggested in the comments).

Answer (score 2):

For below mention seq. code mentioned below didn't work as expected:

CODE:

```
def lindexsplit(some_list, *args):
    # Checks to see if any extra arguments were passed. If so,
    # prepend the 0th index and append the final index of the
    # passed list. This saves from having to check for the beginning
    # and end of args in the for-loop. Also, increment each value in
    # args to get the desired behavior.
    if args:
        args = (0,) + tuple(data+1 for data in args) + (len(some_list)+1,)

    # For a little more brevity, here is the list comprehension of the following
    # statements:
    #    return [some_list[start:end] for start, end in zip(args, args[1:])]
    my_list = []
    for start, end in zip(args, args[1:]):
        my_list.append(some_list[start:end])
    return my_list

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,15]
print(lindexsplit(l, 4,7,9,11))
```

INPUT 1:

```
print(lindexsplit(l, 4,7,9,11))
```

OUTPUT 1:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 0], [11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

INPUT 2:

```
print(lindexsplit(l, 4,7,9,15))
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 0], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], []]
```

Please have a look at the simple and updated function which works for all the cases and if it fails somewhere then please let me know.

CODE:

```
def lindexsplit(List, lindex):
    index_list = lindex
    index_list.sort()

    new_list = []

    print(index_list)

    len_index = len(index_list)
    for idx_index, index in enumerate(index_list):
        if len(index_list) == 1:
            new_list = [List[:index+1], List[index+1:]]
        else:
            if idx_index==0:
                new_list.append(List[:index+1])
                # print('Start', List[:index+1])
            elif idx_index==len_index-1:
                new_list.append(List[index_list[idx_index - 1] + 1:index + 1])
                # print('End', List[index_list[idx_index - 1] + 1:index + 1])
                if List[index+1:]:
                    new_list.append(List[index+1:])
                    # print('End', List[index+1:])
            else:
                new_list.append(List[index_list[idx_index-1]+1:index+1])
                # print('Between', List[index_list[idx_index-1]+1:index+1])

    return new_list


l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
l = [str(ele) for ele in l]
print(lindexsplit(l, [0,1, 8, 14, 15] ))
```

INPUT 1:

```
print(lindexsplit(l, 4,7,9,11))
```

OUTPUT 1:

```
[['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7'], ['8', '9'], ['10', '11'], ['12', '13', '14', '15']]
```

INPUT 2:

```
print(lindexsplit(l, 4,7,9,15))
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
[['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7'], ['8', '9'], ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']]
```

INPUT 3:

```
print(lindexsplit(l, 4,7,9,15))
```

OUTPUT 3:

```
[['0'], ['1'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'], ['15']]
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This answer doesn't really offer much for the OP. Please (re-) read [The help center page _How do I write a good answer?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Note it states: "_Every answer must make at least one **insightful observation** about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"